# line 3, in <module> from app.forms import LoginForm

Tags: python, php, html

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask
from app.forms import LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

This my main file, but I keep getting these errors and have been trying to figure them out. I had no luck for about 5 hours now. The error in this code shows this : line 3, in 
    from app.forms import LoginForm

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('Remember Me')
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')
```

Now this code has error that  line
2, in 
    from config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'

Can someone help me out. I am trying to set up a login page right now.

Comment: Did you mean to add the php tag?